# Why are my Unity scripts compiling but not taking effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, editor

I am working on a Unity project (2019.4.12) using VSCode 2019. My project is built on top of a far more complicated one that someone else wrote, and it pulls from 3 remote repos, has a load of addressables, translates from haxe, and does a lot of other things that are a bit above my head.

Previously I had been working with these 3 repos versioned in a VSCode workspace (that did not include versioning of my unity project file), and things were working smoothly. However, I recently uploaded my project file to its own repo on Bitbucket, and added that to my VSCode workspace as well (with a complicated thing where I had to add one of those other repos as a submodule in my Packages folder).

Now whenever I edit & save my scripts in VS Code and click back into unity, they compile like normal, and the changes show in the code preview in the inspector, but the changes do not update when I run the project. The only way I can get Unity to recognize changes is to restart the editor entirely. I'm worried this has something to do with the git setup (at least that's when my troubles began) but I have no idea how to fix it. Please please can someone point me in the right direction about how to solve this?

I have tried messing with the auto-refresh and external editor settings to no avail. Reimporting/resetting/refreshing the scripts in the project/inspector windows seems to do nothing. I have also experimented with downgrading/removing the VSCode package, but no luck there either.

Please any guidance would be so appreciated!

Comment: What kind of changes? Note that e.g. anything in a serialized field (the once you see in the Inspector) are only the default values and once a value was set vis the Inspector you can change it in code as much as you want but it will always be overruled by the already serialized value from the Inspector. It would help to see the bits of your code you are changing

Comment: It's not anything to do with values specifically, it's any edit at all. I can't even comment out a debug message without having to restart the editor. It's making me lose my mind over here 

Comment: Did you maybe by accident disable the [Preferences -> General -> Auto-Refresh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Preferences.html#General)? Also instead of everytime restarting Unity which of course takes forever you can also select the script in the Assets  right click and click "reimport"

Comment: Yup, I've been compulsively checking auto-refresh, it's very much enabled. For whatever reason "reimport" doesn't help either. Neither did "reimport all" or deleting the ScriptAssemblies folder 

Comment: hmmm never heard of this behavior before ^^ sounds like some very odd bug on your specific system

Comment: I'm kind of new at VSCode...could there a be problem there with how I've structured the workspace or something? The strange thing is it was updating just fine before I put the version control on it...

Comment: Never worked with VSCode only VS and Rider .. what version control are you using? I sometimes had the issue that all three, Rider, SourceTree and Unity try to access the se files so sometimes it lead to hickups where I had to stop SourceTree from tracking changes in the background ^^

Comment: It's just git via VSCode...but I have copied the project a few times since I have started trying to correct this, so potentially it could be that the multiple workspaces are vying for git attention? I don't totally understand how the workspaces work. Maybe I should read up on it 